# Posting Empty values in Angular2 version 2

Tags: javascript, php, angular, typescript

I am getting this output when I try to configure. Why is it posting null values. Best Regards

```
{_body: "↵↵ ↵", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers…}
```

my file.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
// import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Http, Response, Headers, Request, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  // title: string = 'My first angular2-google-maps project';
  lat: number = -1.2590509;
  lng: number = 36.7836213;
  success: string;
  login: {fname?: string, lname?: string, emailadd?: string, phone?: string, message?: string} = {};

  constructor(public http: Http) {


  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  //regassets
  onregassets(form: NgForm) {

    this.submitdata();

   // this.methodt();
  }

  submitdata(): void {
    var link = 'http://africatechpoint.com/isbi/testangular.php';
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('Firstname', this.login.fname);
    urlSearchParams.append('Lastname', this.login.lname);
    urlSearchParams.append('EmailAddress', this.login.emailadd);
    urlSearchParams.append('Phone', this.login.phone);
    urlSearchParams.append('Message', this.login.message);
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString()

    this.http.post(link, body, {headers: headers})
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.success = this.login.lname;
        console.log("Guess what is happening", this.success);
        console.log("sasa mtu wangu", data);
        console.log("Empty Data", data.text());

      }, error => {

        console.log(body);


      });
  }

}


app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComComponent } from './footer-com/footer-com.component';
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyDpBltUoIDcL2KUa3zCiu1TV18tLz_7gTQ'
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularTester</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `body` with a `JSON.stringify({Firstname: "Name"})` type of call?

Comment: @JorgeObregon done it but still not working.

Comment: How did you send back the data from php?

Comment: @JorgeObregon. I am sending inform of json format. It is sending null values.

Comment: @JorgeObregon This is my project in github. see the link below. https://github.com/mainakanyi/africaGeek.

Comment: @JorgeObregon Did you take a look at the github project in the link above?

Comment: @james I didn't. Sorry. I've been swamp with work. As soon as I check it at home, I'll post a reply here

Comment: @JorgeObregon Ok

Comment: @JorgeObregon Did you have a look at it?

Comment: yes sir, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the repo you mentioned (github.com/mainakanyi/africaGeek), I had to reinstall angular-cli. I got the following error when trying to serve the app:

```
$ ng serve
Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies.
The package "angular-cli" has been deprecated and renamed to "@angular/cli".

Please take the following steps to avoid issues:
"npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli"
"npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"
```

That fixed the angular-cli issue. However, running `ng serve` I got:

```
Environment configuration does not contain "environmentSource" entry.

A new environmentSource entry replaces the previous source entry inside environments.
```

The reason for that error is that you were missing `"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts"` in your angular-cli.json. Just add that in line 24 in your angular-cli (above `environments`) so it looks like this:

```
  "scripts": [],
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
```

That repo doesn't have the `file.component.ts` you mentioned in your question.

Comment: @orgeObregon. i did that but I still get the same error. see the link below. https://github.com/mainakanyi/EditedGeek. I am trying to send data from my contact form to my mysql server but it's not posting

Comment: @orgeObregon Did you have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: JorgeObregon Did you have a look at my project? Regards